# Обратная транслитерация

Tags: c#, translit

Пишу транслитератор, а точнее, пытаюсь уже обработанное слово перевести на русский язык.

```
if (Regex.Match(inputtedText, @"^[A-Za-z]+$").Success)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                {
                    inputtedText = inputtedText.Replace(lat[j], rus[j]);
                    inputtedText = inputtedText.Replace(lat[j].ToLower(), rus[j].ToLower());
                } 
            }
            return inputtedText;
```

Все бы хорошо, только одно но: в словаре есть значения, которые составляют больше одного символа("ш" - "sh", "ж"-"zh" и т.д.), а программа распознает только один (т.е слово, с буквой "sh" преобразуется в слово c буквами "c" и "h").
Как лучше поступить в таком случае?

Comment: т.е. лучше использовать dictionary для этого?

Comment: Мой комментарий почему-то исчез, да мне кажется,что с dictionary все будет проще.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов
Я пыталась, но с теми же циклами. Естественно, результат получился такой же. Думаю, что проблема как раз в них. 
Мне, получается, нужно заменить несколько элементов в inputtedText на один, но я не понимаю, как.
А регулярное выражение здесь только для ввода латиницы.

Comment: решение в лоб - заменять сначала более длинные вхождения, но это тоже не всегда будет работать, и например вместо "счастье" можно получить "щастье"

Comment: На самом деле обратная транслитерация - это большая задача, по крайней мере на хороший диплом с последующими научными публикациями. Сейчас я уже ничего не соображаю, если будет время, завтра я попробую глянуть.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, с естественными языками всегда проблемы :)

Comment: @Grundy
попробую, спасибо :)

Comment: Может помочь наличие большого словаря слов, возможно базы данных, и проверка по нему в спорных случаях, когда есть несколько вариантов замен

Comment: @Grundy "...Может помочь наличие большого словаря слов..."- совершенно верно этот словарь называется морфология.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, морфология, как мне кажется несколько более сложная штука :) я имел ввиду просто проверять напрямую полученные варианты, без разбора слова на части и т.д.

Comment: вы можете даже просто перебирать все варианты перевода транслит-русский, и перебирать варианты до того момента, пока перевод результата в транслит не совпадет с изначальной строкой.