# Как реализовать обработку различных значений введенных пользователем?

Tags: c#

Только недавно изучаю C# и столкнулся с проблемой на практике. В зависимости от входного числа (от 1 до 100), которое вводит пользователь, на экран выводится строка:

- если 1 -  "i hate it"
- если 2 -  "i hate that i love it"
- если 3 -  "I hate that I love that I hate it"

и т.д.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать подобное?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а как тут Dictionary поможет?

Comment: что-то вроде: `string.Join(" that ", Enumerable.Range(1,Count).Select(i=>$"i {i%2==1?"hate":"love"}"))+" it"`

Comment: @Grundy это явно сбой на SO. Мой комментарий к этому вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/979117/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F почему-то в момент  когда я писал здесь возник в этом месте, а потом исчез. Я подозреваю, что Dictionary возникло оттуда же :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string Func(byte count) => string.Join(' ', "i hate", string.Join(' ', EnumerableOfStrings().Take(count)), "it");

    for (byte c = 0; c < 10; c++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Func(c));
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> EnumerableOfStrings()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return "that i love";
        yield return "that I hate";
    }
}
```

Сделал тот дополнительный "метод", чтобы легче было писать другие штуки. Если хочешь другой способ - используй в цикле `StringBuilder` и подобие *state machine*

Вот несколько строчек вывода с консоли:

> i hate  it
>   i hate that i love it
>   i hate that i love that I hate it
>   i hate that i love that I hate that i love it
>   i hate that i love that I hate that i love that I hate it